# Partial Blood Moon

Tags: lunar-eclipse

Is it possible for a partial lunar eclipse to be a 2 on the [Danjon scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danjon_scale)? If so, is it possible for [this lunar eclipse](https://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/5MCLEmap/0001-0100/LE0033-04-03P.gif) to have been a 2 on the scale?

Comment: Could you define exactly what you mean by a blood moon? (I gather it's a certain number of lunar eclipses within a short period, but I'm unsure. I seem to be getting a lot of contradictory stuff in a search.)

Comment: @Andy  I'd go with the discussion at https://www.timeanddate.com/eclipse/facts-lunar-eclipse.html

Comment: I reworded the question to be more astronomically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we go with the discussion at [Time&Date](https://www.timeanddate.com/eclipse/facts-lunar-eclipse.html), it would depend on just how 'red' you want the moon to look.  The term "blood moon" is not an astronomical term, nor is it a specific  full moon, such as "blue," "harvest," or even [these](http://farmersalmanac.com/full-moon-names/) .

Comment: see the revised question